# Usage of Cypress.require within cy.origin

Tags: typescript, cypress

I am trying to use `Cypress.require` which was released with 12.6.0 to be able to import external dependencies within a `cy.origin` callback.

According to the documentation this should work with any typescript module:
https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/require

Here is what I tried:

```
// test.js
module.exports = {
    foo: 'bar',
};


// test.cy.ts
describe('Some test', (): void => {
   it('should work', (): void => {
      cy.origin('https://example.com', (): void => {
         const test = Cypress.require('./test.js');
         cy.log('test', test);
      });
   });
});

// cypress config
export default defineConfig({
    e2e: {
        baseUrl: 'http://0.0.0.0:4200',
        supportFile: 'cypress/support/e2e.ts',
        defaultCommandTimeout: 10000,
        video: false,
        experimentalOriginDependencies: true,
    },
});
```

The result of this is an error when starting the test case:

`Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'`

**Update**

Since it was asked in the comments and it might not be clear in the post: I am using typescript successfully in the project (angular) and cypress also runs perfectly with suites written in typescript.
Only the `Cypress.require` breaks it. It's also irrelevant if I require a vanilla JS module or a typescript ES6 module.

**Update 20-02-2023**

After not really finding a cause of the issue, I resorted in downgrading cypress to 12.5.1 which uses `require` instead of `Cypress.require`. This works consistently:

```
// test.cy.ts
describe('Some test', (): void => {
   it('should work', (): void => {
      cy.origin('https://example.com', (): void => {
         const test = require('./test.js');
         cy.log('test', test);
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: Do you have typescript installed through package.json?

Comment: Yes, I am using version 4.7.4 currently. The general setup with typescript and cypress works nominally. Only when I start using Cypress.require I get this error.

Comment: The problem also occurs if you don't use `Cypress.require()` (comment out the line).

Comment: No, the problem doesn't occur if I remove the line.

Comment: Yes, it does. You only need the `experimentalOriginDependencies: true` setting for the error to occur. You may need to restart Cypress to properly test the issue.

Comment: I can not confirm that. If I remove the `Cypress.require`, keeping version 12.6.0 all my suites written in typescript work nominally, even with changing origin. Meanwhile I resorted to downgrade to 12.5.1 and use `require`. I updated my post.

Comment: Experienced the same issue when trying to `Cypress.require()` a cypress/commands file... I think we should go ahead and open an issue in GitHub.

Comment: Done. Feel free to add additional context to the issue: 
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/25885

Answer (score 1):

The issue described in my question was indeed an problem with cypress itself:

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/25885

The fix was released on March 14th and is included in version 2.8.0.